# Firebase Extension - Stripe Payments keeps failing to deploy resources

Tags: firebase, stripe-payments, firebase-extensions

For the past hour I've been trying to install the Firebase Extension for Stripe Payments, and unfortunately it keeps failing to deploy the required resources. May someone might be able to help me debug this and install the extension successfully.

I've tried installing it via the Firebase GUI. as well as via the Firebase CLI, same errors. After attempting to re-install, the extension claims its installed, but unfortunately the functions are still flagged with the error: `Function deployment failed. Try again.` - And I don't know how to manually deploy, other than deploying the entire extension via the CLI, which initially fails with the error.

Upon re-deploying, it appears successful (similar to re-installing in the GUI) but yet again, the functions required are flagged with an error in the GUI as `Function deployment failed. Try...`

Error:

Extensions deploy had errors:

- create firestore-stripe-payments
  ; RESOURCE_ERROR at /deployments/firebase-ext-firestore-stripe-payments/resources/onUserDeleted: {"ResourceType":"gcp-types/cloudfunctions-v1:projects.locations.functions","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":"You may not have more than 32 total max instances in your project"}; RESOURCE_ERROR at /deployments/firebase-ext-firestore-stripe-payments/resources/createPortalLink: {"ResourceType":"gcp-types/cloudfunctions-v1:projects.locations.functions","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":"You may not have more than 32 total max instances in your project"}; RESOURCE_ERROR at /deployments/firebase-ext-firestore-stripe-payments/resources/createCustomer: {"ResourceType":"gcp-types/cloudfunctions-v1:projects.locations.functions","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":"You may not have more than 32 total max instances in your project"}; RESOURCE_ERROR at /deployments/firebase-ext-firestore-stripe-payments/resources/createCheckoutSession: {"ResourceType":"gcp-types/cloudfunctions-v1:projects.locations.functions","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":"You may not have more than 32 total max instances in your project"}; RESOURCE_ERROR at /deployments/firebase-ext-firestore-stripe-payments/resources/onCustomerDataDeleted: {"ResourceType":"gcp-types/cloudfunctions-v1:projects.locations.functions","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":"You may not have more than 32 total max instances in your project"}; RESOURCE_ERROR at /deployments/firebase-ext-firestore-stripe-payments/resources/handleWebhookEvents: {"ResourceType":"gcp-types/cloudfunctions-v1:projects.locations.functions","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":"You may not have more than 32 total max instances in your project"}

Error: Extensions deployment failed.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should review the [README](https://github.com/invertase/stripe-firebase-extensions/blob/master/README.md#update-2023-08-11) and this [issue comment](https://github.com/invertase/stripe-firebase-extensions/issues/524#issuecomment-1671603107) about the transfer of these extensions to another maintainer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the Extension is being taken over by another Dev Studio. Unfortunately the Codebase is still the Same, and even after using the New Extension, the Same Error occurs during Installation.

Answer (score 4):

*Firebaser here*

There's a limit on Cloud Functions quota based on multiple criteria that are checked behind the scenes. Eventually these limits might increase as usage continues. As an immediate workaround,  try setting maxInstances in the `advanced settings` dropdown to <32 instances.

Comment: After a couple trial and error attempts, I noticed that I am able to deploy the extension and functions when NOT changing the location from the default one (Iowa) usually I'd run my functions in the same location as I have my firestore instance (europe-west-3).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I had to discover that there is an issue with Firebase at the current point in time, which means that extensions and functions deployed to europe-west-3 run into this error, but not functions deployed to us-central-1

This happens on legacy projects as well as brand-new projects.

Therefore, the current "Solution" to this problem, is to install the extension, with us-central-1 as the location from where the functions are executed.

Answer (score 0):

On screenshot above, the value of 30 appears to be pulled from the previous successful deployment, whereas the error of >32 applies to the latest deployment attempt that has failed due to quota. As to the quota itself, the answer above from Joe and Iman provides more clues on reasons and a workaround.